# how to show dynamically added cell selected in uitableview

Tags: uitableview

I'm adding cell into uitableview on some action event. The cell is added at the top position in uitableview. I want the newly added cell to be selected by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the method *selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:* of the table view after the cell is added, assuming the cell is added in index 0 of section 0:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewRowAnimationTop]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply. But I'd already tried this and was getting following error
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'

Also if I replace UITableViewRowAnimationTop with  UITableViewScrollPositionNone this then it selects top row when only 1 record in table and later selects every 2nd row.

Comment: @Harshal You need to post your code where you add the new cell so that I can take a look.

Comment: if(self.isNewRecord){
        countOfLogbookRecords=[self.tableView_top numberOfRowsInSection:0]+1;
        [self createRecordWithKeyValue:logbookDictionary className:RECORD_LOGBOOK];
        
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView_top selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:0];
        
    }

here is the code. i'm using core data.

Comment: @Harshal please include it in your question. And where do you call tableView reloadData method to refresh the table view? Or the insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation method?

Comment: hey, you don't need to call reload table method when you insert or delete. but anyways your answer is accepted. Actually i was inserting row in another thread. that's why this problem caused. But thanks a lot.